# GameLoop, What To Put For Delta?

Tags: java

I was just wondering for a quick question, what do you put in for delta exactly. The parameter double delta is (as the developer stated, in seconds of logic updates). If I wanted the loop to run 20 times a second, would I have it set to .2 or something like that? I am a bit confused on the logic updates (in seconds) part.

Anyways if you want to check any more of the game loops provided then check out the page here http://entropyinteractive.com/2011/02/game-engine-design-the-game-loop/

```
public abstract class GameLoop
{
private boolean runFlag = false;

/**
 * Begin the game loop
 * @param delta time between logic updates (in seconds)
 */
public void run(double delta)
{
    runFlag = true;

    startup();
    // convert the time to seconds
    double nextTime = (double)System.nanoTime() / 1000000000.0;
    while(runFlag)
    {
        // convert the time to seconds
        double currTime = (double)System.nanoTime() / 1000000000.0;
        if(currTime >= nextTime)
        {
            // assign the time for the next update
            nextTime += delta;
            update();
            draw();
        }
        else
        {
            // calculate the time to sleep
            int sleepTime = (int)(1000.0 * (nextTime - currTime));
            // sanity check
            if(sleepTime > 0)
            {
                // sleep until the next update
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                    // do nothing
                }
            }
        }
    }
    shutdown();
}

public void stop()
{
    runFlag = false;
}

public abstract void startup();
public abstract void shutdown();
public abstract void update();
public abstract void draw();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You input the time in milliseconds that a single logic-loop should be based on.

If you want 20 times per second then 1/20 second is the number which is not 0.2 but 0.05.

You can write it more intuitively (IMO) by writing "1.0 / 20" then you don't have to convert back and forth and can just replace 20 with the frequency.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably do by your way as it does seem a lot better just by dividing it in the program itself and not outside.